# How to Outer Join a Calendar table to view dates with 0 records

Tags: group-by, count, mariadb, left-join

I have a table with records of orders by customers and a table with dates from Jan 2022 to 10 years. I wanted to get all numbers of customers made everyday for the last 28 days, including those with 0 customers recorded. So I needed to outer join the calendar table to the customer records. However, I cant use outer join correctly.

Here's how I done it:

```
SELECT order_date as 'date', COUNT(orderstatus) as 'customers'
FROM orders
RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendar ON
calendar.date = orders.order_date
WHERE sellerid = 11
```

Im getting:

```
date          customers
2022-01-02    9
```

I wanted to see:

```
date          customers
2022-01-01    0
2022-01-02    9
2022-01-03    0
.
.
.
```

Comment: 'However, I cant use outer join correctly.' - please publish what you tried.

Comment: Which Version you are using

Comment: You have an aggregate function without a group by so only  1 row will be returned..and you are not testing for last 28 days..knowing what version you are on will help decide what an answer might look like..

Comment: @P.Salmon I see, can you please provide a snippet for it as Im not sure how to do it really. Version of what again? I see Server version: 10.4.22-MariaDB, PHP version: 8.0.13,  and phpmyadmin 5.1.3.

Comment: MARIADB is not mysql and is not as much of a drop in replacement for mysql as it used to be I have added a mariadb tag...having said that most mysql answers will be fine in mariadb (so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not get the results that you posted in your question unless you group by date, so I guess you missed that part of your code.

You need a `WHERE` clause to filter the calendar's rows for the last 28 days and you must move the condition `sellerid = 11` to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.order_date, 
       COUNT(o.order_date) customers
FROM calendar c LEFT JOIN orders o
ON o.sellerid = 11 AND o.order_date = c.date 
WHERE c.date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 28 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY c.order_date;
```